# javaScript; increment a variable value, after a return function

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this question is kind of basic, but i am learning closures in JavaScript and i am creating a guessing game, here is my code

```
function guessingGame(amount){
var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var tries = 0;
return function(guess){
  if(guess === answer){
    console.log('Got it')
    return ++tries
  }
  else if(guess > answer){
    console.log('You are too high')
  return ++tries
  }
  else if(guess < answer){
    console.log('You are too low')
  return ++tries
  } 
  if(tries > amount){
    console.log('Number of tries exceeded')
   }
  }
}
```

i am trying to get the `if(tries > amount)` test to work but i am sure i am doing it wrong. Please any help would be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: There's a return statement right above that line, which means it returns before it even gets there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your condition `tries > amount` before any return . Update your code like this

```js
function guessingGame(amount){
var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var tries = 0;
return function(guess){
  if(tries > amount){
    console.log('Number of tries exceeded')
   }
  if(guess === answer){
    console.log('Got it')
    return ++tries
  }
  else if(guess > answer){
    console.log('You are too high')
  return ++tries
  }
  else if(guess < answer){
    console.log('You are too low')
  return ++tries
   
  
  }
  }
}
var guess = guessingGame(2);
console.log(guess(1));
console.log(guess(2));
console.log(guess(3));
console.log(guess(4));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(guess === answer){

  }
else if(guess > answer){
  }
else if(guess < answer){
  }
```

either one of these conditions would always be true hence the last part of the code is never executed

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
function guessingGame(amount){
    var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var tries = 0;
    return function(guess){
        if(tries > amount){
            console.log('Number of tries exceeded')
            return;
       }
       if(guess === answer){
           console.log('Got it')
           return ++tries
       }
       else if(guess > answer){
           console.log('You are too high')
           return ++tries
       }
       else if(guess < answer){
           console.log('You are too low')
           return ++tries
       } 
    }
}
```

You just needed to check the condition in the beginning as one of the if statements before your check will always evaluate to true and that check is an unreachable code.